# Web part only displays after refreshing page?

Tags: error, xslt-list-view-web-part

I've got a web part that displays one item in a list in a custom view. When going to the page that houses the web part, it errors, giving me a

> "Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator."

message. However, simply refreshing the page causes it to display correctly. What is going on here?

Comment: Was this web part created in Designer or in Visual Studio or is it merely an Out-of-the-box web part?  If so, which one?

Comment: @Dave Wise It's just the xslt list view web part.

Comment: Is this happening system-wide or are only specific users having the issue? Could it be browser related?

Comment: @Lori It is happening to two admins so far, on Chrome and IE 8/9. Not a production site yet, so not many users.

Comment: What does the developer dashboard or fiddler show?

Comment: @Lori As far as I can see, nothing too informational. The Dev Dashboard tells me that loading the web part takes over a second when it fails, and much less when it succeeds. Fiddler shows me a 401 followed by a 200 response on the page, and a 401 followed by a 304 response for the css file and the lone image on the page.

Comment: Offtopic: what a lame error msg! Open in SPD? Really? :-O

Comment: @Anders Rask I agree! I did open it in SPD just to humour myself, and didn't find anything out of the ordinary.